# Receiving System.FormatException after using ClientScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, clientscript

I'm trying to code an onclick behaviour for a GridView by using the following codebehind-code:

```
protected void gridProcesses_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gridProcesses, "SelectProcess$" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
    }
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gridProcesses.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            this.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(this.gridProcesses.UniqueID, "SelectProcess$" + row.Cells[0].Text);
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}

protected void gridProcesses_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "SelectProcess")
    {
       //do stuff after click on gridviewrow
    }
}
```

---

After compiling and clicking on a GridViewRow, my gridProcesses_RowCommand is called and enters the "if", since SelectProcess was passed as CommandName, whatever I am trying to do within that code works, but afterwards the program just stops working after throwing the following error:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "System.Web.HttpUnhandledException" wurde ausgelöst. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   bei System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   bei System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   bei System.Convert.ToInt32(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   bei System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
   bei System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   bei System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   bei ASP.processes_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Users\roett04\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4c906b5d\4377a67f\App_Web_qcvmvpfq.0.cs:Zeile 0.
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

---

The same code works just fine if I add a SelectButton and use OnSelectedIndexChanging instead of overriding the render-method and using rowdatabound to add the onclick-handler.

Comment: you mean to say code raise exception at `if` line

Comment: No, that code is executed perfectly, however, Frédéric just posted the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridView` control supports a `Page` command that can use the `CommandArgument` property of the event as a page number. It seems to be failing while converting this property.

Do you perchance assign something to `e.CommandArgument` *outside* of your `if` block? If that's the case, you shouldn't do it, because it will impact commands other than `SelectProcess`.

Comment: Outstanding, that did the trick, thanks a lot!
I set the CommandArgument to a Textvalue within my GridView, unknowing that it might affect other commands.

Comment: I am getting the same problem but am not setting the e.commandArgument anywhere - any ideas?